# I am a famous driver, but do you know me?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I am here, sitting in my car
>   Some good rock in my ears
>   I can feel the power
>   The speed of the vehicle pushing hard on my bum
>   Still the display is null
>
> Sudenly an hard shake makes me realise
>   I can't now hear anything
>   Only deep silence
>   And I see it
>   I see it like never before

Who am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> [Starman in his Tesla Roadster.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk%27s_Tesla_Roadster)

I am here, sitting in my car 
Some good rock in my ears

> The stereo in the Roadster was playing "Space Oddity" by David Bowie

I can feel the power 
The speed of the vehicle pushing hard on my bum 
Still the display is null

> While the rocket accelerated into space Starman was pushed into his seat. He can't see anything because the payload fairing is still in place.

Sudenly an hard shake makes me realise 
I can't now hear anything 
Only deep silence 
And I see it 
I see it like never before

> There's bound to be some shaking when the payload fairing is discarded and the 2nd stage fires up. When the payload fairing is gone he can see the earth/space/mars from a new angle.

Comment: I think this answer fits the riddle best, but it needs some elaboration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the answer, but you should elaborate on it ;)

Comment: Very nice answer that seems like the right one, and far better than mine!

Comment: this is indeed the answer I was looking for, well done :)

Comment: ...but the [display isn't null](https://cdn3.i-scmp.com/sites/default/files/styles/980x551/public/images/methode/2018/02/08/f3f93b3a-0c88-11e8-a09e-8861893b1b1a_1280x720_124021.jpg)

Comment: @DavidStarkey I think they replaced the display with a sign/plaque but I can’t find a solid source at the moment.

Comment: @DavidStarkey  "Display" was more a reference to the dashboard, even if the launcher goes some km/s, the dashboard still display 0 because wheels aren't turning

Answer (score 9):

You are:

> **Baby**, the driver in the movie [**Baby Driver**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Driver)

I am here, sitting in my car
Some good rock in my ears

> The movie opens with the driver sitting in the car listening to music...

I can feel the power
The speed of the vehicle pushing hard on my bum

> ...before leading to a high-speed car chase.

Sudenly an hard shake makes me realise
I can't now hear anything
Only deep silence

> Towards the end of the movie, the driver is ambushed, and a gun shot near his ears to deafen him

And I see it
I see it like never before

> At the end, he sees all the people he helped/ saved during the robberies come forward to testify in his favour.

Comment: Mmmh fits pretty well, but not what I got in mind. Also you didn't answer "Still the display is null"

Comment: Thanks @Flying_whale - quick question, is this a real-life driver you're referring to?

Comment: it is not from a movie/series, if that's your question :)